# How do I pass the scope variables from a controller into the $ionicModal in ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope

I am building an app in Angular using ionic framework I am trying to pass the scope variable **cropImgSrc** to the modal's scope but it does'nt seem to work. Here is my code

**Controller Code**

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('addprofile',function(){
return{
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'client/modules/add-profile-details/add-profile.html',
    controllerAs: 'addProfileController',
    controller: function($scope,$reactive,$ionicModal){
        var vm = this;
        $reactive(this).attach($scope);
        this.helpers({
            imgSrc: function(){
                return '';
            },
            cropImgSrc: function(){
                return '';
            }
        });
        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('client/modules/add-profile-details/crop-image-modal.html', {
            scope: $scope,
            animation: 'slide-in-up'
        }).then(function(modal) {
            vm.modal = modal;
        });
        this.addAvatar = function(files){
            if (files.length > 0) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e){
                    $scope.$apply(function(){
                        vm.cropImgSrc = e.target.result;
                        vm.modal.show();
                });
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
            }
            else {
                this.imgSrc = undefined;
            }
        };
    }
} });
```

And my Template is as follows

```
<ion-view title="Crop Avatar">
<div class="modal">
    <div class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
        <h1 class="title">Your Avatar</h1>
    </div>
    <ion-content>
        <img ng-src="addProfileController.cropImgSrc">
    </ion-content>
</div>
```

Can anyone please guide me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First replace `<img ng-src"addProfileController.cropImgSrc">` with `<img ng-src="addProfileController.cropImgSrc">`

Comment: Sorry it was just a typo when I was copying the content here!

Answer (score 0):

Since the control within modal lies with $scope now, can you try changing this line vm.modal = modal; with $scope.modal= modal; 
Also one option would be to print logs and check the values.

Comment: Tried that but that seems not to pass, I've even checked the official ionic solution but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace all 'vm' with $scope
and replace the modal code like this

```
<ion-view title="Crop Avatar">
   <div class="modal">
      <div class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
         <h1 class="title">Your Avatar</h1>
      </div>
      <ion-content>
         <img ng-src="{{cropImgSrc}}">
      </ion-content>
   </div>
</ion-view>
```